# Authentication with google calender api

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

have been trying to integrate google calender api with salesforce was able to achieved it using auth 2.0 ,has i navigated it to google page for auth ,so now when i was trying to use auth 1.0 with google calender api am seeing these error ,

```
401 Unauthorized

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Just want to know whether it is possible to get the data from google calender api using App Key ,instead of using Auth 2.0 ,

thanks 
XXX